# How to combine both scroll-snap and jQuery .scroll()?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm having difficulty combining both of these in the same project.

If I enable `overflow: scroll`, then my jQuery function doesn't get called, but if I disable it then my jQuery works but not the scroll-snap.

I've tried changing "window" to "#scroll-parent" in the jQuery `.scroll()` but it didn't do anything.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  setMenuColor();
 });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  background: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#scroll-parent {
  //overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The #scroll-parent DIV wasn't in the right place in HTML